# Alternative to Node Class module?

Tags: 7

I'm looking for a simple way to add classes to nodes. I found this module http://drupal.org/project/node_class but it is Minimally maintained.

Just wondering if is there any alternative to this module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check [Skinr](http://drupal.org/project/skinr) module.

If you are only looking for a straightforward way to add classes to nodes, you could do that even without any additional module.

1. Create a field called "css_class"
2. Hide that field from output
3. Edit the node.tpl.php file and print the value in the wrapper element

That should do the trick.